# как можно написать этот фрагмент одной строчкой на питоне?

Tags: python, оформление

```
if work != []:
    return work[0].replace(',','').strip()
return ''
```

Comment: `return publish[0].replace(',','').strip() if publish else ''`

Comment: Написать то можно но зачем??? Главное что бы потом этот код не приходилось читать ) и Вам тоже спустя какое-то время...

Answer (score 2):

В одну строчку вполне нормально в таком случае, но мой взгляд лучше будет просто переписать получше. Например вот так:

```
if work:
    return work[0].replace(',', '').strip()
return ''
```

Так и читабельно, и просто.

Answer (score 1):

```
return work[0].replace(',','').strip() if work else ""
```

либо так:

```
return work and work[0].replace(',','').strip() or ""
```

или так:

```
return next(iter(work), "").replace(',','').strip()
```